# Alarm Manager not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a new scheduler for my app that runs daily on user defined time.Here is the code below. Problem is that scheduler is not running on set time.Please suggest how to do this

```
 private void setAlarm(String targetCal){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String[] Time=targetCal.split(":");
    Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //int days = Calendar.SUNDAY + (7 - timeOff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // how many days until Sunday
    timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR,Integer.valueOf(Time[0].trim()));
    timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.valueOf(Time[1].trim()));
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: timeOff.getTimeInMillis() tells it to at the current time. Then you are asking it run on the same time after a day. Is that you aim to do?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Aim is to run scheduler on set timings

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
    Intent i = new Intent("in.servicealarmdemo.demoactivity");

/** Creating a Pending Intent */
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), count+2, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

/** Getting a reference to the System Service ALARM_SERVICE */
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
/** Creating a calendar object corresponding to the date and time set by the user */
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(pYear,pMonth,pDay,pHour,pMinute);

/** Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since epoch */
long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

/** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time */
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);

/** Alert is set successfully */
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Or you can simply try this tutorial

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/setting-up-alarm-using-alarmmanager-and-waking-up-screen-and-unlocking-keypad-on-alarm-goes-off-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

There might be issues by setting variables. Instead try to find difference between current time and the new value, and then do:

```
timeOff.add(Calender.HOUR,diff);
```

Comment: I am just getting hours and minutes from calendar